# counting rows only if on both days of a weekend

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id|shift|      date|
 1|   s1|2017-08-12|  
 2|   s2|2017-08-14|
 3|   s3|2017-08-20|
 4|   s2|2017-08-26|
 5|   s3|2017-08-27|
 6|   s1|2017-08-28|
```

I'd like to count the number of times any shifts are worked on both days of a weekend (Saturday AND Sunday of the same weekend) and only on both days.

In the example above, the only full weekend worked is 8/26-8/27 so the answer should be 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table with itself. (Join sundays with the the previous day).

```
select count(*)
from yourTable sun -- sunday
join yourTable sat -- saturday
  on  sat.shift = sun.shift
  and sat.date  = sun.date - interval 1 day
where dayofweek(sun.date) = 1 -- sunday
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked.  I had thought of joining the table to itself but couldn't quite get it to work.  Also tried using CASE WHEN... also without success.